# Cannot upload to deployed app's AWS S3 bucket

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-web-services, heroku

I am writing a Ruby on Rails web app with a feature that requires uploading images to AWS. When running the app locally I was able to upload to AWS just fine. However when I deploy to Heroku I run into problems.

When I try to upload images I get an error. My logs show:

```
Aws::S3::Errors::AccessDenied (Access Denied)
```

config/environments/production.rb :

```
config.paperclip_defaults = {
   :storage => :s3,
   :s3_region => ENV.fetch('AWS_REGION'),
   :bucket => ENV.fetch('AWS_BUCKET'),
   :s3_credentials => {:access_key_id => ENV.fetch('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'),
                    :secret_access_key => ENV.fetch('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY')}
}
```

Other things I have done:

- create an IAM user
- upload IAM user's credentials to heroku using `heroku config:set foo=bar`
- edit IAM user's permissions to include `AmazonS3FullAccess`
- add a Bucket Policy

  ```
   {
      "Version": "2012-10-17",
      "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "AllowFileUpload",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
          "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::[**id**]:user/user-heroku"
      },
      "Action": "s3:*",
      "Resource": [
          "arn:aws:s3:::clothes-swapper/*",
          "arn:aws:s3:::clothes-swapper"
          ]
     }
     ]
   }
  ```

Comment: If you set the IAM user to allow full access, you shouldn't need to set a Bucket policy for that user IIRC. Is it an issue with incorrect keys?

Comment: deleted bucket policy. Still does not work

Comment: I can only imagine the issue with your credentials. Did you try to hard code the variables and check if it's working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was a simple issue. All the credentials should have been in the  `:s3_credentials` hash

```
config.paperclip_defaults = {
:storage => :s3,
:s3_credentials => {
                      :bucket => ENV.fetch('AWS_BUCKET'),
                      :access_key_id => ENV.fetch('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'),
                      :secret_access_key => ENV.fetch('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'),
                      :s3_region => ENV.fetch('AWS_REGION'),
                    }
}
```

I also deleted and made new access keys on amazon. That could've solved the issue too.

Answer (score 0):

Check your CORS Config in your bucket's Permission tab. I had a similar problem and updating this fixed it. Update the CORSRule with the Origin and Methods exactly as they are below [image]

Comment: what goes in the cors configuration?

Comment: Updated the answer. More info on the matter: [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/cors.html)

Comment: Thanks for the help but still no luck :(